# gunicorn behave differently when run from terminal and by service

Tags: nginx, django, encoding, gunicorn, unicode

I am using nginx+gunicorn+django for my website.

The following is my gunicorn.conf file:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

# export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
# export LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

exec gunicorn \
    --name=eduwiki \
    --pythonpath=eduwiki \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --log-level debug \
    --log-file /var/log/gunicorn/error_logs.log \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    eduwiki.wsgi:application

#    --access-logfile  /var/log/gunicorn/acclogs.log \
```

When I run

```
service gunicorn start
```

And when I change to the dir `/home/django`, the following command (which is the same as the codes in the former config file) worked like a charm:

```
exec gunicorn     --name=eduwiki     --pythonpath=eduwiki     --bind=0.0.0.0:9000     --log-level debug     --log-file /var/log/gunicorn/error_logs.log     --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py     eduwiki.wsgi:application
```

But the first one cannot be started, when I remove the logging part in the config file:
    exec gunicorn \
        --name=eduwiki \
        --pythonpath=eduwiki \
        --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
        --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
        eduwiki.wsgi:application
With`service gunicorn start`, the service runs. But it behaves differently from directly running in terminal.

When running directly from terminal, the character encoding showing in the webpage is correct, like the following:

> *Mathematics (from Greek μάθημα máthēma, “knowledge, study, learning”)*

But when I run gunicorn using service, the encoding of non-ascii character is totally wrong:

*

> Mathematics (from Greek ?????? m?th?ma, ?knowledge, study, learning?)

  *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interactive terminal sessions is typically automatically populated with locale `LC_ALL` and language settings `LC_LANG` and  `LANG` and many SSH clients will override the server defaults by forwarding those environment variables from your workstation.

Often those are different from the system defaults, which get used when a daemon starts as a service from the start-up scripts. Uncomment the `# export` lines in the start-up script and populate the environment with suitable settings.

Comment: You are right. Instead of `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, I should have used `env LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` which follows the syntax of the system V script. That's the reason why `export` did not work and I commented it.